# Mapping a response to a class in Java

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am developing new feature.
I want to get the countries that allowed to retrieve data for a specific endpoint.
the request returns this response

```
{
    "response": {
        "mobile_web": {
                "countries": {
                    "at": {
                    "start_date": "2014-12",
                    "end_date": "2017-12",
                    "fresh_data": "2018-01-23"
                },
                "br": {
                    "start_date": "2014-12",
                    "end_date": "2017-12",
                    "fresh_data": "2018-01-23"
                },
                "id": {
                    "start_date": "2014-12",
                    "end_date": "2017-12",
                    "fresh_data": "2018-01-23"
                },
                "il": {
                    "start_date": "2014-12",
                    "end_date": "2017-12",
                    "fresh_data": "2018-01-23"
                },
                "in": {
                    "start_date": "2014-12",
                    "end_date": "2017-12",
                    "fresh_data": "2018-01-23"
                },
                "it": {
                    "start_date": "2014-12",
                    "end_date": "2017-12",
                    "fresh_data": "2018-01-23"
                },
                "jp": {
                    "start_date": "2014-12",
                    "end_date": "2017-12",
                    "fresh_data": "2018-01-23"
                },
                "ph": {
                    "start_date": "2014-12",
                    "end_date": "2017-12",
                    "fresh_data": "2018-01-23"
                },
                "pl": {
                    "start_date": "2014-12",
                    "end_date": "2017-12",
                    "fresh_data": "2018-01-23"
                },
                "pt": {
                    "start_date": "2014-12",
                    "end_date": "2017-12",
                    "fresh_data": "2018-01-23"
                },
                "ru": {
                    "start_date": "2014-12",
                    "end_date": "2017-12",
                    "fresh_data": "2018-01-23"
                },
                "th": {
                    "start_date": "2014-12",
                    "end_date": "2017-12",
                    "fresh_data": "2018-01-23"
                },
                "tr": {
                    "start_date": "2014-12",
                    "end_date": "2017-12",
                    "fresh_data": "2018-01-23"
                },
                "us": {
                    "start_date": "2014-12",
                    "end_date": "2017-12",
                    "fresh_data": "2018-01-23"
                },
                "world": {
                    "start_date": "2014-12",
                    "end_date": "2017-12",
                    "fresh_data": "2018-01-23"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to map it to this class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class ReportResponse {

        @JsonProperty("response")
        public Result response;

        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        public static class Result {
            private Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

            @JsonAnyGetter
            public Map<String, Object> any() {
                return result;
            }

            @JsonAnySetter
            public void set(String name, Object value) {
                result.put(name, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the line sending the request and receiving the response is:

```
ReportResponse report = executeRequest(url, ReportResponse.class);
```

the result is:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihVFZ.png)

Now, How could I get to the countries map as the report?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the inner class. Make `Result` as a separate class instead of inner class. Everything should work fine. Also why is ReportResponse static ? Is it inside some other class? If not its wrong.

If at all you need to use inner class then you should use

`@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = ANY)` on your inner class

And make sure you have proper getter and setter for all the fields.